# How to add email address in header (from field) in wp_mail

Tags: wordpress

I have created contact us form for users where user can add their email address and name. I wish to add these name and email address field in wp_mail headers.
I am using following code.
    `$headers = 'From: My Name <test12df432abc@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";`
    `wp_mail($to, $subjects, $message, $headers); // not working`
    `wp_mail($to, $subjects, $message ); // working`

I think this happening is because my From: address doesn't match to the domain i'm  sending the email from. But is there any way for me to accomplish above using wp_mail.

I am getting following debugging information using smtp debug

2017-02-12 13:48:40 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2017-02-12 13:48:40 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2017-02-12 13:48:40 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "*** *.*.* Service closing transmission channel

                                      "
2017-02-12 13:48:40 SERVER -> CLIENT: *** *.*.* Service closing transmission channel
2017-02-12 13:48:40 Connection: closed

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$headers = array(
  'From: My Name <test12df432abc@gmail.com>'
);
$headers = implode( PHP_EOL, $headers );
wp_mail( $to, $subjects, $message, $headers );
```

`PHP_EOL` will add the proper line break based on the system it's on (where `\r\n` is for Windows, `\n` is for Unix). Using `implode()` will make sure it's only added if needed. In this case, you're only sending one header so the line break isn't neaded anyways. But if you want to send more headers:

```
$headers = array(
  'Bcc: secretuser123@aol.com',
  'From: My Name <test12df432abc@gmail.com>',
  'Reply-To: webmaster@hotmail.com'
);
$headers = implode( PHP_EOL, $headers );
wp_mail( $to, $subjects, $message, $headers );
```

Comment: Hi Joe thanks for reply.  I tried your code but i am receiving same error. I from email i wish to set may be anything like gmail,rediffmail, or any other and my server email address is from another domain. may be this is causing issue. if you have any input on this please share.

Comment: Are you using any SMTP plugin or authentication? The `wp_mail` code I provided is correct assuming those variables are set; so, the issue is somewhere further down the line.